# Is there a way to change node text in bootstrap treeview?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-treeview

Is there a way to change node text in bootstrap treeview without redrawing the whole tree or removing/adding the node?

I checked here: https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview and here: https://github.com/patternfly/patternfly-bootstrap-treeview but there seem to be no method like "updateNode" or "renameNode".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply select the node and update its parameters -

```
node = $('#tree').treeview('getNode', <nodeId>);
node.text = '<new value>';
$('#tree').treeview(true).removeNode([]); // refresh hack available in the development github branch.
```

Comment: I accepted this as an answer but to be honest I already switched to jsTree. It seems it has much larger user base and getting help is easier.

Comment: Right, the treeview indeed lack some basic functionalities (adding/removing nodes), I remember I had to initialize it every time the tree changed. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code to change the tree node, without having to update the whole view.

```
var e = $(node.$el).find(".text");
e.html(value);
```

But in order for that to work, you have to set wrapNodeText to true, as this creates a span.text around the text, which make it possible to change.